# How to get the direction of text from PDF using PDFBox API

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have PDF files which has text in four different orientations like horizontal aligned ,vertically aligned and inversely aligned. While using PDFBox API to read the text from pdf, I am getting good output for horizontally aligned text but not in other cases.
For example if "italic" word is horizontally aligned , the output is "italic". If it is vertically aligned, then the output is splitting across the lines as
"it 
 a
 li 
 c"(here "it", "a","li","c" are in different lines).
I want to know whether there are any ways to get good outptut even for vertically and inversely aligned text.

Comment: Unfortunately you do not share a sample PDF. While there are PDF fonts for vertical writing, I would assume the fonts in your PDF are not of that kind. If my assumption is correct, that "*vertically aligned*" text actually consists of chunks of normal, horizontally aligned text arranged across multiple lines. Thus, the output *splitting across the lines as "it a
li c"* would be correct.

Comment: If my assumption is wrong, though, PDFBox still won't extract the text as you desire as it is implemented with horizontal text in mind. In this case, though, you might have luck overriding `org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.writePage()` accordingly.

Comment: Can you please share the code that you used, as I am facing similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can override processTextPosition() method of PDFTextStripper and write the logic to get direction, x and y values for each character. By grouping the characters based on its direction, you can crop them seperately.

Comment: Its look promising. Thank you..will try and let you know the result